# updating state for a nested array (one-to-many relationship) without having to refresh page

Tags: reactjs, one-to-many, server-side-rendering, setstate

In my project, a user may have many budgets, and each budget may have many expenses. I am using a Ruby on Rails backend and performing a fetch to localhost with my React.js frontend. I want to be able to create,update and delete for both the budgets and the expenses. So the POST request works and returns something like this :

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"category": "transport",
"amount": 200,
"user_id": 1,
"expenses": [
{
"id": 127,
"budget_id": 1,
"description": "transport expense",
"date": null,
"amount": 20,
"created_at": "2020-07-09T06:15:50.287Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-09T06:15:50.287Z"
}
]
},
{
"id": 4,
"category": "a new budget",
"amount": 200,
"user_id": 1,
"expenses": []
},
{
"id": 5,
"category": "new budget",
"amount": 2000,
"user_id": 1,
"expenses": [
{
"id": 125,
"budget_id": 5,
"description": "new expense",
"date": null,
"amount": 30,
"created_at": "2020-07-09T06:15:34.533Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-09T06:15:34.533Z"
},
{
"id": 126,
"budget_id": 5,
"description": "another new exp",
"date": null,
"amount": 30,
"created_at": "2020-07-09T06:15:43.071Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-09T06:15:43.071Z"
}
]
}
]
```

My component tree looks something like this :

[image]

While I am able to delete things from the backend, items (budget/expense) don't appear to delete until I refresh the page.
I have the following function living in Budget.js in order to deduct the totals of expenses from the budgets (which should update whenever an expense is added/deleted/updated which only happens once I refresh):

```
  handleBudgetChange = () => {
    let total = 0

    total = this.state.expense.reduce(
      (prevValue, currentValue) => prevValue + currentValue.amount, 0);
    let budgetRemaining = this.props.budget.amount - total 

    this.setState({
      remainingBudget: budgetRemaining
    })
  }
```

I have the state of Budget living in App.js and the state of Expenses living in Budget.js (also, the state of expense is set equal to the props of the budget---- this is because I needed to have the ability to match the created expenses with the appropriate budget and for some reason this wouldn't work any other way).

If anyone has ANY TIPS whatsoever on how to fix this issue.. I've been stuck on it for days. I also am not very familiar with react (and have 0 familiarity with hooks and redux) so any help would be much appreciated. I would be happy to provide any additional info/code if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your problem is that you want to show the updated budget/expense without refreshing the page. So here are my suggestions -

1. **Without making an extra api call** -

   - **Handle it in the frontend** - You need to update your react state once you add/update/delete an expense or budget. It doesn't involve any extra api call. You need to write the logic in the frontend to update your state. This might be hectic if you have highly nested objects.
   - **Send updated values in the api response** - You can send the updated values in your POST/PUT/DELETE api response and in the frontend, simply use this response to update your state.
2. **Make an extra api call** - After you perform an add/delete/update action (probably you are calling any PUT/POST/DELETE api), call the same GET api that you are calling to get the data initially. With this GET api response, simply update the state.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your local state of `budgets` and `expenses` after getting the response from server of a CRUD operation.

Following example of code might help you

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            budgets: []
        };
        this.handleBudgetChange.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Expense onBudgetsChange={this.handleBudgetChange} />
                {/* rest of your code */}
            </div>
       );
    }

    handleBudgetChange(budgets) {
        this.setState({
            budgets: budgets
        });
    }
}
```

**Expense.js**

```
class Expense extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            expenses: []
        };
        this.handleBudgetDelete.bind(this);
        this.handleExpenseDelete.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* your render logic */}
                <button onClick={this.handleBudgetDelete}>Delete Budget</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleExpenseDelete}>Delete Expense</button>
                {/* rest of your code */}
            </div>
        );
    }

    async handleBudgetDelete(id) {
        // call api and get updated budgets list
        const response = await api('/url-to-delete-budgets', id);
        this.props.onBudgetsChange(response); // notify parent component to update state
    }

    async handleExpenseDelete(id) {
        // call api to delete expense
        await api('/url-to-delete-expense', id);
        // update local state
        this.setState({
            expenses: this.state.expenses.filter(e => e.id !== id)
        });
    }
}
```